# serving static content on a Jersey web app with descriptor-less deployment

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jersey, jetty

I am creating a **REST** based web application and using the latest version of **Jersey** and embedded **Jetty**. Descriptor-less deployment for **Servlet 3.0** allows the exclusion of **web.xml**. However, I am having trouble understanding how you can serve static content in this case (.html, .css, .js and image files)? As the application is using embedded Jetty, I am not deploying this in a standalone servlet container, so the resulting file is a shaded **.jar**. Perhaps, I need to use the **WAR** plugin to make this possible? If so, where exactly do I have to place the aforementioned files? Is it still possible with packaging into **.jar** only as well?

The only way I have been able to serve static content so far, was with direct filesystem access, like this (Jersey's JAX-RS part):

```
@GET
@Path("manager/preview/img/loader.gif")
@Produces("image/gif")
public final Response preview() throws Exception
{
    final byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("manager/preview/img/loader.gif"));

    return Response.ok().entity(b).build();
}
```

This definitely does not seem like the appropriate way. I'd be thankful, if someone could point me in the right direction.